auto-insert-mode picks the wrong template if in $HOME
I created two template files template.c and template.h in my ~/.emacs.d/autoinsert.
I have this in my ~/.emacs.d/init.el:
; Insert default content for new files
(auto-insert-mode)  ;;; Adds hook to find-files-hook
(setq auto-insert-directory "~/.emacs.d/autoinsert/") ;;; *NOTE* Trailing slash important
(setq auto-insert-query t)
(define-auto-insert "\.c" "template.c")
(define-auto-insert "\.h" "template.h")

If I create a new c file in /tmp/, emacs uses the correct template.c.
However, if I create a new c file in ~, emacs uses template.h.
Why does emacs select the h template for a c file, but only if I am in my home directory?

You need to escape the backslash in a string:
...
(define-auto-insert "\\.c" "template.c")
(define-auto-insert "\\.h" "template.h")

Otherwise, the CONDITION part of the first element in auto-insert-alist (the h entry) is .h and since it's a regexp, the . matches any single character (except newline) and so the first entry matches /home/<anything>.
You should also probably limit the match at the end of the suffix, so e.g. .class does not match the .c condition:
(define-auto-insert "\\.c$" "template.c")
;; or ...
(define-auto-insert "\\.c\\'" "template.c")


EDIT in response to comment: Backslashes are confusing because they are used as an escaping mechanism in multiple places. In a regex, the dot needs escaping so that the regex parser should not misinterpret it as the any metacharacter. So you need to escape it with a backslash (that's role 1: escaping metacharacters in regexes). The trouble is that regexes are represented as strings and the string parser in elisp uses backslash as its own escape mechanism: \n in a string e.g. is interpreted as a newline, \t is interpeted as a TAB character, \f is interpreted as a FORM FEED character (^L), \a is interpreted as a BEL character (^G) but most other \<char> sequences are interpreted as the character itself (e.g. \p is just p). That's role 2: escaping characters in a string - note that this has nothing whatsoever to do with regexes. But now the question is: how do you insert a literal backslash in a string like a  Windows path name which uses literal backslashes, e.g. "C:\path\in\Windows\of\a\file\named\foo"? Try typing that in your *scratch* buffer and evaluating it with C-j: you will get
"C:pathinWindowsof^G^Lile
amed^Loo"

No backslashes anywhere!
The answer is: you escape the backslash, i.e. double-up the backslash - IOW, \\ in a string is interpreted as a single literal backslash. The string that you have to give to elisp should be "C:\\path\\in\\Windows\\of\\a\\file\\named\\foo". The doubled-up backslashes are really a single literal backslash in the string (e.g. "a\b" has length 2 - it consists of the two characters a and BACKSPACE); and "a\\b" has length 3 - it consists of the three characters a, \ and b).
So a regex that matches any character followed by a c is .c and the string representation of this regex is ".c". A regex that matches a literal . followed by c is \.c and the string representation of that regex is "\\.c".

Thanks, working now! I'm not sure why two backslashes, though. I understand that the dot needs escaping, but I though the single backslash would do that?

See edit - hope it helps.

Aargh - I forgot to surround a bunch of things with backquotes and then a third meaning of backslash (it's used as an escape character in the version of Markdown that SE uses) screwed up the display of them. Sorry about that: I think I fixed everything, but if you see something strange, please let me know.
